# Running ASP.NET and VB.Net in Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ubuntu

I have a LAN-based application programmed in ASP.NET with VB as its code-behind. Also, MYSQL for the database. I just want to ask if I can run my application in UBUNTU? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Mono-Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). Its a portation of the .NET framework to Linux-based operating systems.

However, it is not fully .NET 3.5 compatible and behaves different in some situations. Therefore, you may have to rewrite some code.

Comment: when some years ago checked mono basic it was completely unusable.

Comment: Mono has many differences from .NET, so you need to pay much attention 

http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Portability

Comment: As far as I know, Mono was developed in C# right? Is there any problem if I run my application programmed in VB.net?

Comment: As both C# and VB.NET are compiled to IL there should be no difference.

Comment: +1 , Even though this question can be marked as duplicate :), i just saw similar ones asking for "linux .net frameworks" yesterday!

Comment: @winSharp93 Although C# and VB.Net are both compiled to IL there still could be differences. VB.Net code might require the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, I don't know whether that's included in Mono. Furthermore VB.Net uses some features of IL that C# doesn't, for instance exception filters. See here http://blogs.msdn.com/clrteam/archive/2009/02/05/catch-rethrow-and-filters-why-you-should-care.aspx

Comment: @winSharp93 Some tool should compile your vb.net code into IL. and that _tool_ called compiler, and if compiler lacks some of must have features ... you know that))